# How to access module version in Crystal Lang?

Tags: crystal-lang

I see that a frequent convention is to add a file often named `version.cr` or named after the module it is attached to. Inside of that file, there is a definition of the module with `VERSION = "[semver]"`. How can I access that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the namespace operator `::`, this can be achieved with `Module::VERSION` where `Module` is the name of the module you're trying to access it from.